# « Toutes les réunions doivent être rapportées » ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique

> 10. Exposer, dans un rapport, l'état d'une question que l'on a reçu mandat de suivre : Rapporter les décisions d'une commission.
>     ([*Larousse en ligne*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rapporter/66519))

Je lis dans une politique d'entreprise : « Toutes les réunions doivent être *rapportées* ».

Quel est le sens de ce propos, s'agit-il d'une formulation usuelle et cohérente et devait-on formuler différemment ?

Answer (score 4):

> La formulation me fait penser à une mauvaise traduction de l'anglais
> (*All meetings should be reported*) que je traduirais par « Toutes les
> reunions devront faire l'objet d'un compte-rendu ». ([Graffito](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53834/toutes-les-r%C3%A9unions-doivent-%C3%AAtre-rapport%C3%A9es#comment114659_53834))

Answer (score 2):

Ce sont les décisions, les conclusions qui sont rapportées c'est-à-dire transmises, communiquées. Ce sont les comptes-rendus qui sont rapportés, transmis, communiqués.

C'est par métonymie que l'on dit "les réunions sont rapportées", c'est moins compréhensible. S'agit-il de la programmation des réunions ?

Le problème de l'utilisation de rapporter est que, sous l'influence de l'anglais *to report*, il peut signifier "signaler, dénoncer".
https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/21362/les-emprunts-a-langlais/emprunts-semantiques/emploi-deconseille-de-lemprunt-rapporter

L'autre problème du verbe rapporter est la multiplicité de ses significations dont, en droit administratif " Retirer (un texte législatif ou réglementaire) de l'ordre du jour d'une assemblée, revenir sur (sa décision), en créant une situation analogue à une situation antérieure, sans pour autant provoquer une abrogation ou une annulation de principe."

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapporter

Answer (score 0):

> [Oui](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53840/26366), c'est un anglicisme, « rapporter » tout court n'a pas ce sens en
> français. À la rigueur on peut dire « toutes les réunions doivent être
> rapportées par écrit à... » en précisant qui. ([guillaume31](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53834/toutes-les-r%C3%A9unions-doivent-%C3%AAtre-rapport%C3%A9es#comment114662_53834))